# detect/set immutable on a file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file

I am in need of a ruby way to detect if immutable is set on a file. If it is I need to remove it. Make my change to the file and then return it to immutability. I have looked at File and Fileutils,  I have searched but all I can find with immutable and ruby is how to make ruby objects and threads immutable, which is of course a different thing then what I am looking for. I am trying to avoid using the shell, I want to stick to ruby code if at all possible. I am imagining code something like this:

```
file_name = '/boot/grub2/grub.cfg'
was_immutable = false
if File.immutable?(file_name)
    FileUtils.chattr '-i', file_name
    was_immutable = true
end
#my changes
if was_immutable
    FileUtils.chattr '+i', file_name
end
```

Comment: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3595183

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might seem like an over-simplification, but you can probably see where it is going:

```
file_name = '/boot/grub2/grub.cfg'
a = %x[lsattr #{file_name}].chomp
puts a if a[/i/]
```

Ok, so based on the link in the comments below, here is what I could come up with as a ruby version (if a guru around, happy to see how this should look):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'fcntl'

FS_IOC_GETFLAGS = 0x80086601
EXT3_IMMUTABLE_FL = 0x00000010
$count = 0

def check(filename)
    fd = IO.sysopen(filename, Fcntl::O_RDONLY)
    f = IO.new(fd)
    a = [0].pack("L_")
    f.ioctl(FS_IOC_GETFLAGS, a)

    unless a.unpack('L_')[0] & EXT3_IMMUTABLE_FL == 0
        puts "#{filename} is immutable :- a[0] = #{a[0].to_s}"
        $count += 1
    end

    f.close
end

ARGV.each do |arg|
    Dir[arg + '/*'].each do |item|
        check(item) if File.file?(item)
    end
end

exit(1) unless $count == 0
```

Comment: Thank you for adding this and I should have mentioned in the question, which I will edit. I had thought of just using command lines, but I want to have this be as pure a ruby implementation as possible. So I am looking for the ruby way to do it if I can. Otherwise I guess I will have to shell out.

Comment: Found this python script which you might be able to alter to ruby:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132795/how-to-search-for-files-with-immutable-attribute-set

Comment: While that may be a solution, after having looked at it I am afraid I don't have the needed knowledge to translate that into ruby. I am not entirely sure I understand what it is doing or how I would call appropriate ruby calls to duplicate it's effects.